# Call variable from servlet and display it in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

My scenario is I have a user.java servlet and I have a variable `user`. Now I want to display the value of `user` variable in my 4 jsp. My question is how to call the variable in from servlet to jsp. I read to used `getRequestDispatcher` but it can pass the variable in one jsp. Please any suggestions.

Comment: What is this `user` variable? Would you mind to show your code, so we can understand your use-case better? (Anyway, your last two question suggest you should read [a tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partwebtier.htm) first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a value through out the application (in any jsp you want),you can set it in context.

You can use ServletContext object to set it in Context.

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();

context.setAttribute("name","value");
```

You can use the context-param element, subelement of web-app, to define the initialization parameter in the application scope

```
<web-app>  
 ......    
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>parameterName</param-name>  
    <param-value>parameterValue</param-value>  
  </context-param>  
 ......  
</web-app>
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he needs. IMHO he's looking for storing the `user` variable in session, but to be sure, we need to see his code.

Comment: Thank you very much it did work. . I have a question, it will work too if the value of my variable is from database?

Comment: @Prince Mani Gupta. Thank you very much it works perfectly. ur the man